# OpenMP reduction: min gives incorrect result

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, g++, openmp

I want to use an OpenMP reduction in a `parallel` region, outside a `for` loop. According to the [OpenMP reference](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-4.0-C.pdf), reduction clauses can be used in `parallel` regions, so no `for` loop or `sections` should be necessary.

However, when using an OpenMP `reduction (min:...)` in a `parallel` region, I'm getting incorrect results. If I use exactly the same structure for a `reduction (max:...)` however, the result is correct. If I use a loop for the min reduction (`#pragma omp for reduction (min:...)`), the results are correct, but I don't think that should be necessary. Here's my code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    auto minVar { std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };
    auto maxVar { std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    auto minVarLoop { std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int threadNo { omp_get_thread_num() };

        #pragma omp reduction (min:minVar)
        minVar = std::min(minVar, threadNo);
        // minVar = minVar < threadNo ? minVar : threadNo; // also doesn't work
        
        #pragma omp for reduction(min:minVarLoop)
        for (int i=0; i<omp_get_num_threads(); ++i){
            minVarLoop = std::min(minVarLoop, threadNo);
        }
        
        #pragma omp reduction (max:maxVar)
        maxVar = std::max(maxVar, threadNo);
    }
    std::cout
        <<   "min thread num: " << minVar
        << "\nmax thread num: " << maxVar
        << "\nmin thread num from Loop: " << minVarLoop
        << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output, with 16 threads, is

```
min thread num: 0
max thread num: 15
min thread num from Loop: 0
```

The output I get is

```
min thread num: 12 // or any other number between 0 and 15
max thread num: 15
min thread num from Loop: 0
```

I'm compiling using g++ version 10.3.0 on Ubuntu 21.04, using only the flag `-fopenmp`.

What am I overlooking?

EDIT: *not* initialising `minVar`, i.e. using `int minVar;` somehow makes it work, but I don't find that a satisfying solution. Also, attempting the same with `maxVar`, makes *those* results incorrect. Oh my.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a feature that is not yet supported by the compiler.  If you compile your code with `-Wall` you will see that GCC 10.3.0 shows this warning:

```
red.cc:15: warning: ignoring ‘#pragma omp reduction’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   15 |         #pragma omp reduction (min:minVar)
      |
red.cc:24: warning: ignoring ‘#pragma omp reduction’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   24 |         #pragma omp reduction (max:maxVar)
      |
```

If you correct the code, like I'm showing below using the correct spelling (see [scope Construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpse17.html#x64-640002.9)) the compiler will still object, as it does not support version 5.1 of the OpenMP API yet:

```
red.cc:15: warning: ignoring ‘#pragma omp scope’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   15 |         #pragma omp scope reduction (min:minVar)
      |
red.cc:24: warning: ignoring ‘#pragma omp scope’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   24 |         #pragma omp scope reduction (max:maxVar)
      |
```

The correct spelling would then look like this:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    auto minVar { std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };
    auto maxVar { std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    auto minVarLoop { std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int threadNo { omp_get_thread_num() };

        #pragma omp scope reduction (min:minVar)
        minVar = std::min(minVar, threadNo);
        // minVar = minVar < threadNo ? minVar : threadNo; // also doesn't work
        
        #pragma omp for reduction(min:minVarLoop)
        for (int i=0; i<omp_get_num_threads(); ++i){
            minVarLoop = std::min(minVarLoop, threadNo);
        }
        
        #pragma omp scope reduction (max:maxVar)
        maxVar = std::max(maxVar, threadNo);
    }
    std::cout
        <<   "min thread num: " << minVar
        << "\nmax thread num: " << maxVar
        << "\nmin thread num from Loop: " << minVarLoop
        << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The varying results are due to a race condition.  Don't ask why you're getting the right result for max, I do get different results any time, I run the code.

Another correct version (not needing bleeding edge support for version 5.1 of the OpenMP API) of your code would be this:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    auto minVar { std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };
    auto maxVar { std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    auto minVarLoop { std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };

    #pragma omp parallel reduction(min:minVar) reduction(max:maxVar)
    {
        int threadNo { omp_get_thread_num() };

        minVar = std::min(minVar, threadNo);

        #pragma omp for reduction(min:minVarLoop)
        for (int i=0; i<omp_get_num_threads(); ++i){
            minVarLoop = std::min(minVarLoop, threadNo);
        }

        maxVar = std::max(maxVar, threadNo);
    }
    std::cout
        <<   "min thread num: " << minVar
        << "\nmax thread num: " << maxVar
        << "\nmin thread num from Loop: " << minVarLoop
        << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought
```#pragma omp parallel <newline> { <newline>  #pragma omp reduction```
is the same as
```#pragma omp parallel reduction```, just like it is with ```#pragma omp parallel for```. So that's wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  `reduction` is a clause that needs to go with a directive like `parallel`, `for`, or `parallel for` (and some others, like newer `scope` construct).

Comment: One last question: Does setting the outer clause to the one above, i.e.
```#pragma omp parallel reduction(min:minVar) ...```,
have any implications for nested clauses, such as ```for``` or ```sections```? From your code, it looks like it's fine, but that's surprising to me.

Comment: Yes, it does have implications.  Note, the `reduction` on the `for` in my code is on a different variable.  You could not have the same variable in a reduction on `parallel` and the `for`.

Comment: Okay, as long as there are no other implications, your solution works for me, thank you!

Comment: I actually need the reduction in a ```while``` loop inside the parallel region. Then, putting the ```reduction``` clause at the outermost level doesn't work. Any idea?
i.e. ```#pragma omp parallel <newline> { while(condition){ #pragma omp reduction(min:minVar) <newline> ... } }```